# Modifying Arguments passed by reference in the function call in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, reference, rvalue, lvalue

Here is a simple code that takes counter as a reference passed argument and then prints it :

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Fun(int &counter, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
      return;
    Fun(counter+1,n--);
}


int main() {
    int counter = 0;
    int n = 5;
    Fun(counter,n);
    cout<<counter<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error.

```
  prog.cpp: In function ‘void Fun(int&, int)’:
prog.cpp:7:16: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
     Fun(counter+1,n);
                ^
prog.cpp:3:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Fun(int&, int)’
 void Fun(int &counter, int n)
  ^
```

Can somebody please help, why this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Fun(counter+1,n--);` you are not passing `counter` to the function. You create a temporary from `counter+1` that you pass to the function. To extend the life of a temporary taken by reference, it needs to be `const`, so `void Fun(const int &counter, int n)` would be compileable.

Counter will however be `0` when the function ends since you never change `counter` and the function will never return since you do not decrease the `n` you pass to the function. You call the function with `n` and *then* decrease `n`.

An alternative:

```
void Fun(int &counter, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
      return;
    Fun(counter += 1, n - 1); // or Fun(++counter, --n);
}
```

Both `counter += 1` and `++counter` return a reference to `counter` which is why this works.

`counter++` and `n--` will however *not* work, because the [post-increment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) operators return temporaries too, like in:

```
int old = n;
n = n - 1;
return old;
```

Comment: This will cause infinite recursion as the same value of `n` is passed to the recursive call.